# Can you set an object name as input from a texbox?

Tags: c#, object, textbox

I'm making a scheduling app, and I'm stuck on my profile setup page.
Login has a drop-down to select profile (not doing credentials, it's just a final for school), or you can create a new profile.

After clicking New Profile, it brings up a screen with a textbox and associated button - this is where they enter their name. I want the associated button to instantiate an object of class Employee with their name as the object name (i.e. if they enter "John Smith", I want the Employee object that represents their profile to be called JohnSmith or John_Smith)

Right now, this is what I've got for the click action on the button:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string newName = txtName.Text;
        Employee employeeName = new Employee(newName);
    }
```

It will set up an object, whose name property will be established correctly, but I want the object name (currently employeeName) to be the person's name.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: you can't use a different variable name as far as i know

Comment: Your requirement is rather strange. Why change an object name dynamically? The enduser does not interact with object name instead she interacts with the properties and methods of objects.

Comment: I know it's unorthodox, but I need each profile to have a unique object name obviously. I just need help figuring out how to make the object names unique and relevant to the individual.

Comment: You might be able to use an object initializer like so `var employeeName = new Employee() { Name = newName };`

Comment: Will that work if I don't have a constructor with 0 parameters?

Comment: To deal with multiple objects, each with a different name, you could use LIST<Employee> aPerson = new LIST <Employee>() where 'Employee' is a class, other structures can be used such as DataTable.

Comment: Add your Employee object to a **Dictionary** with the name as the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects themselves don't have names. Names of variables/fields are there only of programmers to read code and can change without impacting meaning of the program.

In most cases to represent "name of an entity" you pick property of your choice and use it to refer/find particular object in collections/DBs.

```
class Employee 
{
  ....
  piblic string Name {get;set;}
}

Employee GetByName(string name)
{
     return listOfAllEmployees.Where(e => e.Name = name);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to set it up to name them profile# (i.e. first profile is profile1, next click creates profile2, then profile3, etc)? After that, you're saying I should just use the name property to refer to a specific profile?

Comment: @JackYoung to name objects "profile1,..." you need to either store  latest number, or (assuming you store collection of all "profiles") you can iterate all items and see what latest id is from existing items (may be easier to store such number as separate filed too in addition to name if it make sense from data point of view).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just want to see the person's name in the debug watch.

In this case use [DebuggerDisplayAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228992%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
public class Employee
{
   [DebuggerDisplay("Name= {Name}")]
   public string Name{get;set;}

   public Employee(string name)
   {
       Name = name;
   }
}
```